# Stream for DocumentSnapshot in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, future

I want to create a `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` in flutter to use in `StreamBuilder`. I know I can do this using:
`Firestore.instance.document("path").snapshots()` 
but I want a custom `Stream` so that I can control the rate at which my document is read. I would like to use `Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds:5), ...)`.

Help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create you own stream and add the documents to it.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (_) async{

     myStreamController.sink.add(
          await Firestore.instance.collection("Path").getDocuments()
     );
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried an alternate approach. What I did was used a ```Timer.periodoc``` whose callback changes the value of a ```ValueNotifier``` and I am using a ```ValueListenableBuilder``` to detect change. It works but cache capacity goes on increasing. Will this also happen if I use ```Stream``` and ```StreamBuilder```. Thanks in advance.